# How to pass an id from one page to the next one and insert it in a table as foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to PHP. After taking snippets from different places it concluded to this. Im trying to put the id from the first page in the link and take it from there with the `$_GET` option on the second page. Afterwards, im taking the variable as parameter for the sql statement but it still fails to execute the insert command.

//from the first page

```
$last_id = $link->insert_id;

echo "New record inserted sucessfully! ^_^";

header('location: register1.php?id=' . $last_id);

die();
```

// after inserting the user credentials i store the id and put it in the link

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";

$username = $password = $confirm_password = $result = $userid ="";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = $name_err = 
$param_id = "";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $userid = $_GET['id'];
```

//getting the id parameter

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, password, user_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $param_username, 
$param_password, $param_id);

        // Set parameters 
        $param_id = $userid;
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // Creates a password hash

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: example1.php");
            die();
        } else {
            die('An error has occured. Please try again 
later.' . mysqli_error($link));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Store the ID in the session. Don't believe  any input by the user and especially never the user id. Otherwise it's very easy to take over an account!

Comment: `header('location: register1.php?id='.$last_id);` might be prone to [HTTP header injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection) .. i believe the more modern PHP versions has fixed this..